# How loop map from corner to mid?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

I have a squared map(python),each point is represented as a coordinate of (y,x).I want to know,how to loop through each point in a "circle"  (picture).
.I have no idea how to start,whether with for or while loop,but I think that for-loop is quite useless here.I'm really lost.I'm not solving anything,I'just curious about this. Thanks !

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. What did you try so far? And what was the exact issue you encountered along the way? Please edit your question to specify this.

Comment: `for x in range(numcols): for y in range(numrows):`.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @zondo probably not.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty nice exercise, but you'd try at least something yourself.

Comment: Do you need the coordinates? One approach would be to consume the first column and then rotate (reverse and transpose) the rest. Otherwise, go for the obvious but tedious and have fun.

Comment: This looks like a task for a generator that `yield`s `(x, y)` tuples. Of course, the generator will use loops. Your image already has a big hint on what these loops look like: The same-coloured arrow paths of ever decreasing length.

Answer (score -1):

One possible way to approach your problem is to think of it in terms of walking it. You start by walking down 5 steps, then turn left and walk another 5 steps. With each direction your are walking in, you just need to change one of your coordinates by 1 (or -1) and leave the other unchanged.

With this idea you could create a list of directions, down would increment `y` but leave `x`, i.e. `(1, 0)` would be added on each step. When you turn left, `y` stays the same but you increment `x`, i.e. `(0, 1)` would be added, and so on for each direction. You would then have `4` directions to cycle through.

Next you need to figure out how many steps are needed in each direction.

Python provides a tool for cycling through a list of entries repeatedly called `cycle`. Each time `next` is called it gives the next entry in the list of directions.

So the following should get you started:

```
from itertools import cycle, repeat

walk = [0, 0]
direction = cycle([(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)])

for steps in [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]:
    offset = next(direction)
    for step in range(steps):
        print walk
        walk[0] += offset[0]
        walk[1] += offset[1]
```

If you are not allowed to use any libraries, then you will need to think about a different way to cycle through each of the directions, which I will leave you to try and think about.

The next step could be to try and generalize this idea to work with squares of any size by thinking about how to construct your step list automatically.